# Newly receive message is not retrieving from my own Default SMS App Inbox

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-contentprovider

I am working on a project in which I have made app to default sms app and getting new message body and notification through Broadcast Receiver. It is showing toast that new message has been received and also read new message body.

But problems are

Problem 1:

The newly received sms is not retrieving from my default sms app inbox and not showing in my listview.

Problem 2:

I am not able to get each and every message from each conversation

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

    if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
        SmsMessage msg = null;
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            }
            if (messages.length > -1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());

                MyNotificationManager.getInstance(context).displayNotification(messages[0].getOriginatingAddress(), messages[0].getMessageBody());

            }
        }
    }
```

}

Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-sdk android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>



<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.ughareja.whocaller.utils.App"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity android:name="com.ughareja.whocaller.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />      
        <receiver android:name=".smsReciever.SmsListener"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".smsReciever.MmsReciever"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".smsReciever.ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".smsReciever.HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>   
    </application>
```

Can you tell me How to save receive message ?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: I post AndroidManifest file now

Answer (score 0):

To receive, I suggest changing your manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".smsReciever.SmsListener"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".smsReciever.MmsReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In addition, you will need to declare the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>
```

You shouldn't be doing so much work on the receiver, send it to an intentReceiver instead:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Timber.i("Intent received: " + intent.getAction());

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Intent intentServiceIntent = new Intent(context, SMSIntentService.class);
        intentServiceIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startService(intentServiceIntent);

        //send broadcast to networkAvailableReceiver
        Intent intentNetworkBroadcastReceiver = new Intent();
        intentNetworkBroadcastReceiver.setAction("Youraction.CHECK_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY");
        context.sendBroadcast(intentNetworkBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Here's what I use to parse out the message:

```
private fun parseOutMessages(intent : Intent?) {

    val msgsAny : Array<Any>
    var sender: String?
    val msgBody: String
    var bundle = Bundle()
    if (intent != null) {
        bundle = intent.extras as Bundle
    }

    try {
        //parses out the message
        val pdus = bundle.get("pdus") as Array<Any>
        val msgs = Array<SmsMessage?>(pdus.size, {null})
        for (i in msgs.indices) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val format = bundle.getString("format")
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i] as ByteArray, format)
            } else {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i] as ByteArray)
            }

            // Here you have the sender(phone number)
            sender = msgs[i]?.originatingAddress
            //is the message long enough to send?
            var messageBodyLength = 0

            if (msgs[i] != null) {
                val message = msgs[i] as SmsMessage
                messageBodyLength = message.messageBody.length
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Timber.e(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping i solved it now my mistake was that i used new ContentResolver when receive message